# Javascript , Object property is shown as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, typescript

I have a json response from a service that looks like:

retrievedData:

```
{
  "35736":{"Id":0, "Name":"car"}
  ,"48973":{"Id":0, "Name":"book"}
  ,"41981":{"Id":0, "Name":"dog"}
}
```

I want to get properties values using the numeric keys, for example:

```
console.log(retrievedData["35736"]);
```

There is a list of elements that it is iterated. Each element has a "serial" that matches the key property value.

When I use the hardcoded value:

```
console.log(retrievedData["35736"]);
```

It displays the correct object, but when I build the key like this:

```
var a = String('"' + JSON.stringify(element.Serial()) + '"');
console.log(retrievedData[a]);
```

it returns `undefined`.

```
resultList.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log("retrieved data, Serial:" + element.Serial());
    var a = String('"' + JSON.stringify(element.Serial()) + '"');
    console.log(a);

    console.log(retrievedData[a]);

    console.log(retrievedData["35736"]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The output values, console logs:

```
retrieved data, Serial:35736
v.ts:199 "35736"
v.ts:204 undefined
v.ts:206 Object {Id: 35736, Name: ""....
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Remove double-quotes wrapping the key building: `String(JSON.stringify(element.Serial()));`

Comment: You're right @hindmost, now it works! :)

Comment: Try `var a = element.Serial().toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it returns undefined.

Its because you have `('"' + JSON.stringify(element.Serial()) + '"');` The string will be something like `""35736""` not `"35736"`

Also using `String` constructor is a *very bad practice* as its unconventional (e.g. `typeof` will be different)